# VB.NET Reference the user form in which the sender control is located

Tags: vb.net, parent, sender

I wonder how do I reference the user form in which the sender control is located? I have a programmatically created button control and user form in which it's located and when clicking on it I need to reference the user form to grab a value from a combobox in that form to use it as a variable and I can do it descending i.e. get the sub control of the sender but how do you get the control above the sender?

```
Sub DynamicForm_NewForm_SmartHUB_ProjectsActivated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

        strProjectTypeFolderName = '(form in which the sender is located).combobox_ProjectType.selecteditem

    End Sub
```

Comment: Have a look at the control's `Parent` property.

Comment: The Activated event can only be raised by a Form class, so all you have to do is cast.  If the name is misleading then use FindForm() to find the sender's parent form.

Comment: ``Debug.Print(sender.Name)`` from this sub does return the correct name of the form but I can't seem to be able to do ``strProjectTypeFolderName  = sender.combobox_Projecttype.selecteditem``

Answer (score 1):

You'd first need to cast the `sender` as `Control` at least. You can then access the `Parent` property, although that property is type `Control` and may not be a form, if the `sender` is in a `Panel`, `GroupBox` or some other container. You ought to call the `FindForm` method instead. It will return a `Form` reference and it will also get the containing form no matter how deeply the `sender` is nested.

If you have `Option Strict On`, which you probably don't but you definitely should, even a `Form` reference won't be sufficient. The `Form` class has no `combobox_ProjectType` field, so you'd need to cast it as it's actual type - `Form1` or whatever - in order to access that field without using late binding.

Comment: I do have ``option explicit on`` and I can't reference form by it's name because it's programmatically created and named and it's name may vary

Comment: I might care that you have `Option Explicit On` if I'd mentioned that in my answer, but I didn't so I don't. If you're saying that you haven't created a dedicated form class but are just using a `Form` object then there's definitely not going to be a field named `combobox_ProjectType`, so that code won't work even with late binding. That sounds like a different question though, for which we would need more information. You asked how to get the form and my answer addresses that.